# Find the linear fractional transformation that maps the circles |z-1/4| = 1/4 and |z|=1 onto two concentric circles centered at w=0?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am very close to the solution I think. Since the circles cross the real axis, I want to find mappings from $z \to w$ such that $1/2 \to m$ and $0 \to -m$ and $-1 \to n$ and $1 \to -n$. Using
$$ w = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$$
we get
$$ \frac{a+2b}{c+2d} = -\frac{b}{d}$$
and
$$ \frac{b-a}{d-c} = - \frac{a+b}{c+d}$$
but where do we go from here? I am a little lost in the simplifying algebra here to solve for the $a,b,c,d$ in the transformation.

Comment: Do you know the (holomorphic) automorphisms of the unit disk? You have fewer degrees of freedom if you constrain that $1$ and $-1$ are fixed points (so the unit circle is mapped to itself), and the small circle is mapped to a small circle centered at $0$ inside the unit disk.

Comment: @DanielFischer, Would this mean that 1 maps to -1 and -1 maps to 1? Or that 1 maps to 1 and -1 maps to -1? If you have time for an answer or explanation, that would be great! Thanks.

Comment: I thought of $1\mapsto 1$ and $-1\mapsto -1$. Of course we could rotate thereafter to swap the points. What about my question, do you know the automorphisms of the unit disk? [That's relevant for deciding what to explain and how.]

Comment: @DanielFischer No, actually I am just learning about linear transformations. I'm awake that the interversion $w=1/z$ maps circles and lines to circles and lines. I am also aware of the form $w=(az+b)/(cz+d)$. Although, I'm not specifically aware of the automorphism of the unit disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from your ansatz, we can reduce the degrees of freedom by positing that we want to map $1 \mapsto 1$ and $-1\mapsto -1$. If your ansatz works at all (it does, but one needs to know a bit about Möbius transformations to know that a priori), we can achieve that by afterwards dividing by $n$.

That gives us the relations

\begin{gather}
a+b = c+d\\
a-b = d-c\\
(a+2b)d = - (c+2d)b
\end{gather}

for the desired transformation. From the first two, we obtain $a = d$ and $b = c$, so inserting that into the third, we get

$$(a+2b)a = - (b+2a)b,$$

and that becomes

$$a^2 + 4ab + b^2 = 0,$$

or

$$(a+2b)^2 = 3b^2.$$

We can normalise $b = 1$ (since $b = 0$ would lead to $a = 0$ and that doesn't yield a Möbius transformation), then $(a+2)^2 = 3$ gives us $a = -2 \pm \sqrt{3}$.

Let's pick $a = -2-\sqrt{3}$. So we look at

$$T(z) = \frac{(-2-\sqrt{3})z + 1}{z -(2+\sqrt{3})}.$$

That gives us

$$\begin{aligned}
T(1) &= \frac{-1-\sqrt{3}}{-1-\sqrt{3}} = 1; & T(-1) &= \frac{3+\sqrt{3}}{-3-\sqrt{3}} = -1;\\ T(0) &= \frac{1}{-(2+\sqrt{3})} = -(2-\sqrt{3}); & T\left(\tfrac{1}{2}\right) &= \frac{-\sqrt{3}}{1-2(2+\sqrt{3})} = \frac{-\sqrt{3}}{-\sqrt{3}(2+\sqrt{3})} = 2-\sqrt{3};
\end{aligned}$$

and the four points are mapped as desired. Since $T(\mathbb{R}\cup \{\infty\} = \mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$, and the original two circles intersected the real line at right angles, the two image circles also do that, hence their centres are real, and since the intersections of the image circles with the real line are symmetric with respect to $0$, the centre of both is $0$.

Comment: Thank you! How did you obtain the first two relations from my guess? You must have used my last equality somehow but I'm not sure how you manipulated it to achieve $a+b=c+d$ and $a-b=d-c$.

Comment: The first two are just $$\frac{a\cdot 1 + b}{c\cdot 1+d} = 1;\; \frac{a\cdot(-1)+b}{c\cdot(-1)+d} = -1,$$ multiplied with the denominators to get rid of the fractions.

Comment: Does the third follow from the fact that we want to map $1/2 \to m$ and $0 \to -m$? Also, are there any good resources for learning more about these? Book recommendations maybe? Based on your answer, it seems like there's much more to linear fractional transformations than my book describes.

Comment: Yes, the third is just $T(0) = -T(1/2)$, after getting rid of the denominators. Any decent book on complex analysis should cover Möbius transformations sufficiently, but not necessarily all in one place. At some point, the automorphism groups of the sphere, the unit disk, and the upper half-plane should be discussed, and the transitivity properties that guarantee that one can always do the desired with a transformation fixing $1$ and $-1$ are discussed there.