# Mapping Circles by Möbius Transformation

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to find a Möbius transformation which takes the circles $|z|=1$ and $|z-\frac{1}{4}|=\frac{1}{4}$ to concentric circles. I can assume that the images are centered at $0$, and that the unit circle is mapped to itself and the point $1$ is fixed. So I'm looking for a function of the form $Tz=
\frac{z-a}{\overline{a}z-1}\frac{\overline{a}-1}{1-a}$.

I tried using $a=4$ which maps $\frac{1}{4}$ to $0$, but this doesn't work. So I'm not sure how to choose $a$.

Comment: Möbius transformations don't preserve Euclidean centres of circles. Try choosing $a$ so that $T(0) = - T(1/2)$. [Also this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1030394/find-the-linear-fractional-transformation-that-maps-the-circles-z-1-4-1-4-an).

Comment: Thanks. I see the idea now.