# Mapping $|z|=1$ and $|z-\frac{1}{4}|=\frac{1}{4}$ into concentric circles using the cross ratio

Tags: complex-analysis, linear-transformations, cross-ratio

The question: Find a linear transformation which carries $|z|=1$ and $|z-\frac{1}{4}|=\frac{1}{4}$ into concentric circles and find the ratio of the radii.
This question is already answered here: [Find the linear fractional transformation that maps the circles |z-1/4| = 1/4 and |z|=1 onto two concentric circles centered at w=0?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1030394/736765)

However, I was hoping to be able to set this problem up straight from the beginning using the cross ratio.  So, from the above solution, I can use, where $w=f(z)$, $f(1)=1$ and $f(-1)=-1$.  But I am a bit confused on how to handle the circles.  For instance, if I was given a circle and then given the circle that it is mapped into, I could find a symmetric point and use the symmetry principle.  But, in this case, I am not sure what these circles would map into.  So, we have $(w,1,-1,y)=(z,1,-1,x)$.... and I am not quite sure what I could use for $x$ and $y$.  Also, maybe I can't even use $f(1)=1$ and $f(-1)=-1$.... I was only going to use that based on the solution given in that problem.  My initial thoughts were to let $a$ be the center of the resulting circles, and then we could use $f(0)=a$ and $f(\frac{1}{4})=a$, but I would still need to find the "$x$" and "$y$" mentioned above.
Any thoughts would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $a$ and $b$ are symmetric with respect to both circles $C_1: |z|=1$ and $C_2: |z-\frac{1}{4}|=\frac{1}{4}$ then the Möbius transformation $f$ defined by
$$
 f(z) = (z, \infty , a, b) =  \frac{z-a}{z-b}
$$
has the desired properties: $0$ and $\infty$ are symmetric with respect to both $f(C_1)$ and $f(C_2)$ so that both images are circles centered at the origin.

(One could choose $f(z) = (z, c, a, b)$ for arbitrary $c \ne a, b$, that would only multiply $f$ by a constant factor.)

It remains to determine $a$ and $b$. The symmetry of $C_1$ and $C_2$  with respect to the real axis suggest to try it with  *real* numbers: Then

- $a, b$ are symmetric wrt to $C_1$ if $ab=1$, and
- $a, b$ are symmetric wrt to $C_2$ if $(a-1/4)(b-1/4) = 1/4^2$.

It follows that $ab=1$ and $a+b=4$, i.e. $a, b$ are the solution of the quadratic equation
$$
 z^2 - 4z + 1 = 0 \iff z = 2-\sqrt 3 \, \vee \, z = 2+\sqrt 3 \, .
$$
Without loss of generality we can choose $a=2-\sqrt3$ and $b = 2 + \sqrt 3$. Then
$$
 f(z) = \frac{z-a}{z-b} = \frac{z-(2-\sqrt 3)}{z-(2 + \sqrt 3)} 
$$
maps $C_1$ and $C_2$ to concentric circles, and the ratio of the radii is
$$
 \left | \frac{f(-1)}{f(0)}\right| =  \frac{(a+1)b}{(b+1)a} = b = 2 + \sqrt 3 \, .
$$

Comment: Thank you, @Martin!  Quick question: the bullet points that you made about symmetry, can you elaborate on this a little more?  When it comes to finding points of symmetry, I am only aware of the formula given on page 81 of Ahlfors.  i.e. the symmetric point of $z$ is $z^{\star}=\frac{R^2}{\bar{z}-\bar{a}}+a$, where R is the radius of the original circle and $a$ is the center of the original circle.

Comment: @User7238: It is the same formula: If both the center $a$ and $z$ are real numbers then it simplifies to $(z^*-a)(z-a) = R^2$.

Comment: Ah, I see.  @Martin, so you are, in the formula you mentioned, letting $z^{\star}=a$ and $z=b$?  Is this because they have to map to concentric circles so it doesn't really matter which you let be which?
Also, the $\infty$ that you are using in the cross ratio, can you tell me why you are using $\infty$ besides, say, $0$ or some other number?

Comment: @User7238: Yes to the first part of your question. – As I said in the answer: “One could choose $f(z) = (z, c, a, b)$ for arbitrary $c \ne a, b$, that would only multiply $f$ by a constant factor.”

Comment: one last question, and I really do thank you for helping me with this, but when you found the ratio of the radii, where are the $-1$ and $0$ inputs coming from?  I am assuming the input $0$ corresponds to $C_1$, since that circle is already centered at the origin.

Comment: @User7238: The *image circles* are centered at the origin, so that we can take an arbitrary point on each image to determine the radii and their ratio. Here $f(0) = a/b$ is a point on the image of $C_2$, and $f(-1) = (a+1)/(b+a)$ is a point on the image of $C_1$.